# SAS DATA: How to remove observations that only occur once

Tags: sas, datastep

In SAS, suppose I have a dataset named "person_groups".  It has two variables, named "person" and "group". This dataset simply assigns each person to a group.

How can I remove from this dataset all persons who have no one else in their group?  In other words, how can I remove all singleton groups?

[I'd be happy with a `proc sql` solution or a `data step` solution--either is fine.]

Side note: I'm new to SAS.  I have been using C++ and MATLAB for many years.  I feel like I can't understand how to do *anything* with the SAS DATA step.  It seems extremely clunky, bizarre, and inelegant.  Frankly, I'm growing very frustrated.  Anyone out there have hope for the weary? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way that uses a data step. This method requires a sort.

```
data person_groups;
 input person $ group $;
 datalines;
John Grp1
Mary Grp3
Joe Grp2
Jane Grp3
Frank Grp1
;

Proc Sort data=person_groups;
 by group;
run;

Data person_groups;
 set person_groups;
 by group;
 if first.group and last.group then delete;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Using "by" statements and "delete" statements in data steps seems very useful.  Knowing them, I think I can do much more now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `PROC SQL` solution:

```
proc sql;
   delete from person_groups
   where group in (
      select group
      from person_groups
      group by 1
      having count(*) = 1
      );
quit;
```

As you can see, `PROC SQL` mostly follows standard ANSI syntax, so your existing SQL skills should be quite portable.  And hang in there with respect to SAS Data Step programming; the language is extremely rich, full featured, and by no means "inelegant".  You may have seen inelegant code, but that's more likely the fault of the programmer.  Take a few minutes and read the [SAS Concepts manual](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Maybe I should try to rely on proc sql more than SAS data step, at least until I learn more about data step programming.  Can proc sql do a very large percentage of the things that data step can do?  Thanks, I will definitely read that manual.

Comment: One handy aspect of the data step is that when you are doing a MERGE and you identify your data sets with an IN= option, you are able to determine the merge status of each record. You get this with one pass in a data step, but I believe it would take multiple passes with PROC SQL. Although, each data set must be sorted prior to the data step, so it may end up being a wash efficiency wise.

Comment: I definitely recommend learning data step techniques if you're going to use SAS.  I imagine most things can be done in either, but there are definitely things that you'd rather do in the data step - like this one, presumably; I would expect the data step solution to be faster.